# Plot two regression lines (calculated on subset of the same data frame) on the same graph with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I have this kind of data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),y=c(2,11,24,30,45,65,90,110,126,145), a=c(0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.8,0.9))
```

Using ggplot, I would like to plot on the same figure two regression lines, calculated for a subset of my data frame under condition (a > or < 0.5).

Visually, I would like that both regression lines:

```
df_a<-subset(df, df$a<0.5)

ggplot(df_a,aes(x,y))+ 
  geom_point(aes(color = a), size=3.5) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", size=1, color="black") +
  ylim(-5,155) +
  xlim(0,11)
```

[image]

```
df_b<-subset(df, df$a>0.5)

ggplot(df_b,aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = a), size=3.5) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", size=1, color="black") +
  ylim(-5,155) +
  xlim(0,11)
```

[image]

Appear on this figure:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+ geom_point(aes(color = a), size=3.5)
```

[image]

I've tried with `par(new=TRUE)` without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a flag variable, and use group:

```
df$small=df$a<0.5
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,group=small))+geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="lm")
```

and have yourself pretty colours and a legend if you want:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,group=small,colour=small))+geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image: ggplot with two fits]

Or maybe you want to colour the dots:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y,group=small)) + 
   stat_smooth(method="lm")+geom_point(aes(colour=a))
```

[image: with coloured points]